# Counting values inside pandas groupby aggregate with other functions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, aggregate

I have been looking for an answer without success ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200718/pandas-for-groupby-value-counts-return-the-rows-with-the-maximum-count),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331252/count-and-concatenate-integer-in-pandas-groupby),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby)) and a lot of the questions I have found about string aggregation involves **only** string aggregation when all the columns are strings. This is a mixed aggregation with some specific details.

The df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Group': ['Group_1', 'Group_1','Group_1', 'Group_1', 'Group_2', 'Group_2', 'Group_2', 'Group_2', 'Group_2', 'Group_2'],
    'Col1': ['A','A','B',np.nan,'B','B','C','C','C','C'],
    'Col2': [1,2,3,3,5,5,5,7,np.nan,7],
    'Col3': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,3,2,3,4,5,5],
    'Col4_to_Col99': ['some value','some value','some value','some value','some value','some value','some value','some value','some value','some value']
})
```

[image]

The function used for the output ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440495/pandas-groupby-multiple-aggregate-apply-with-multiple-columns)):

```
def join_non_nan_values(elements):    
    return ";".join([elem for elem in elements if elem == elem])  # elem == elem will fail for Nan values
```

The output:

```
df.groupby('Group')[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].agg({'Col1': join_non_nan_values, 'Col2': 'count', 'Col3':'mean'})
```

[image]

The output expected:

[image]

The output for `Col1` and `Col2` is a counting. The left side is the value, the right side is the count.

PD: If you know a more efficient way to implement `join_non_nan_values` function, you are welcome! (As it takes a while for it to run actually..) Just remember that it needs to skips missing values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def f(x):
    c = x.value_counts().sort_index()
    return ";".join(f"{k}:{v}" for (k, v) in c.items())

df["Col2"] = df["Col2"].astype('Int64')
df.groupby("Group")[["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]].agg({
    "Col1": f,
    "Col2": f,
    "Col3": 'mean'
})
```

It gives:

```
         Col1         Col2      Col3
Group                                  
Group_1  A:2;B:1  1:1;2:1;3:2       NaN
Group_2  B:2;C:4      5:3;7:2  3.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling `value_counts()` inside `groupby().apply()` and convert the outcome into strings using the `str.join()` method. To have a Frame (not a Series) returned as an output, use `as_index=False` parameter in `groupby()`.

```py
def func(g):
    """
    (i)  Count the values in Col1 and Col2 columns by calling value_counts() on each column 
         and convert the output into strings via join() method
    (ii) Calculate mean of Col3
    """
    
    col1 = ';'.join([f'{k}:{v}' for k,v in g['Col1'].value_counts(sort=False).items()])
    col2 = ';'.join([f'{int(k)}:{v}' for k,v in g['Col2'].value_counts(sort=False).items()])
    col3 = g['Col3'].mean()
    return col1, col2, col3

# group by Group and apply func to specific columns
result = df.groupby('Group', as_index=False)[['Col1','Col2','Col3']].apply(func)
result
```

[image: res]